# Android complicated schematic view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-vectordrawable

I need to make an interactive research fragment for my game and got an SVG file exported from Figma with all the rects, circles, texts, etc. It must be scaleable (zoomeable via touch input), draggable (already implemented) and clickable. Clickable means detecting clicks separately for each "block". Also some blocks need to be shadowed on runtime.

Can anyone recommend me the direction to dig info to make such level layout in Android?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I hope help this site, please try it sir.**
[please check graphical flow chart view](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6779)